# $B \subset \mathbb{R^3}$, such that $B = \rm{Fr} (\Omega)$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

$B \subset \mathbb{R^3}$, such that $B = \rm{Fr} (\Omega)$

Where $\Omega = \{(x,y,z) : z \leq 1\}$ and $\rm{Fr}(\Omega)$ means the $\Omega$'s boundary.

Comment: Are you asking to prove the title statement? Please make the content of the post *self-contained," using complete sentences and such that you're asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = (\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}) \cap \Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking "What's the frontier of the subset of $R^3$ consisting of all points whose $z$-coordinates are no more than $1$?"

The answer is $$B = \{(x, y, 1) : x, y \in {\mathbf R} \}$$.

Comment: No. A subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ that his frontier is all points whose $z$-coordinates are no more than 1.

Comment: Are you certain you read his problem correctly? The variable $x$ is the only one that's restricted in his description of the set.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to match the changed question.

Comment: Sorry. My question isn't clear. I need to found a set that his frontier is $\Omega$. Not the $\Omega$'s frontier.